# How to draw a polygon and save it to image using Node.js

Tags: node.js, image, drawing

I'm trying to create an image, draw polygon shapes on it and save it to a file in Node.js, but I'm having a hard time finding a library that can achieve that.

In addition, I would prefer a library that doesn't require the installations of third party programs.

Example of an image I'm trying to create:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without having to use any library you can just write the SVG image.

```js
const fs = require('fs')

const result = `
    <svg
    width="541"
    height="271"
    >

        <rect
            width="541"
            height="271"
            x="0"
            y="0"
            fill="#3d5ea1"
        />

        <polygon
            fill="white"
            points="100,50 400,100 320,200 80,230"
        />

    </svg>
`

fs.writeFile("./file.svg", result, (err) => {
    if (err) {return console.err(err)}
    console.log("The file was saved!")
});
```

This code will create a similar image like the one on your example In case you need a png or jpeg you can use any external library to transform the svg.